# javaFX: как нарисовать quadraticCurve без прямой

Tags: javafx

Дамы и Господа, есть следующий код:

```
public void draw(GraphicsContext gc) {
    gc.beginPath();
    gc.moveTo(x + a.x, y + a.y);
    gc.quadraticCurveTo(x + controlPoint.x, y + controlPoint.y, x + c.x, y + c.y);
    gc.closePath();
    gc.stroke();
}
```

Выводимый результат на экран буквально следующий:
[image: Отрисованная фигура]

как мне убрать прямую линию?, чтобы получилось следующее?[image: картинка, которую нужно получить]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

чтобы получить нужный эфект нужно убрать строку:

```
gc.closePath();
```